# Windows 7 black screen boot and ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, windows-7

After dual boot installation Ubuntu 20.04 & windows 7 , Ubuntu 20.04 is working fine but windows 7 also boots but a black screen shows , I am also able to log in, by just typing password and listening to the login sound.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you see windows 7 after you login, or do you still see this black screen? Also, add some details about your computer model and specifications.

Comment: Did you try booting windows in safe mode?